# GoogleJsonResponseException for Google+ API

Tags: java, android, google-plus

In my Android application I am integrated the Google+ API, I have already verified the access and scopes. I  want to insert the comments and New Post in my android application. I am integrated the Post method with google documentation. The reference is https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

MainActivity.java

```
   //Set the accesstoken
         GoogleCredential credential = new 
  GoogleCredential().setAccessToken( token );

    // Create a list of ACL entries
            PlusDomainsAclentryResource resource = new PlusDomainsAclentryResource();
            resource.setType("domain"); // Share to domain
            List<PlusDomainsAclentryResource> aclEntries =
                    new ArrayList<PlusDomainsAclentryResource>();
            aclEntries.add(resource);

            Acl acl = new Acl();
            acl.setItems(aclEntries);
            acl.setDomainRestricted(true);  // Required, this does the domain restriction

  // Create a new activity object
            com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Activity   activity = new com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Activity()
                    .setObject(new com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Activity.PlusDomainsObject().setOriginalContent(comments))
                    .setAccess(acl);
//Execute the API
            com.google.api.services.plusDomains.model.Activity plusDomains = new PlusDomains(common.HTTP_TRANSPORT, common.JSON_FACTORY, credential ).activities().insert("me",activity)
                    .execute();
```

I got the below Error. I Refer the below links but not its not working

[Google coordinate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445265/google-coordinate-authentication?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 
Unauthorized
W/System.err: {
W/System.err:   "code" : 401,
W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
W/System.err:     "location" : "Authorization",
W/System.err:     "locationType" : "header",
W/System.err:     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
W/System.err:     "reason" : "authError"
W/System.err:   } ],
 W/System.err:   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
W/System.err: }
```

Comment: Are you authenticating as a user with a gmail.com email address or a paid G Suite user?

Comment: gmail.com @abraham

Comment: gmail.com account's can't use the Google+ Domains API.